# What role does this it take?

Tags: pronouns

> He said that after murdering the magistrate, the Mafia looked for more targets. And it plotted to blow up the magnificent, ancient tower in Pisa. The Mafiosi were aiming to strike a major psychological blow at the height of their war with the state.
>
> . . .
>
> On the other hand, at about the same time as the alleged plot in Pisa, the Mafia did bomb the famous Uffizi art gallery in Florence. ***It*** was clearly in the mood to strike at the kind of historic monuments that are the pride of Italy.
>
> –– [BBC Learning English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/language/wordsinthenews/2014/01/140124_witn_pisa.shtml)

Does ***it*** refer to previous act - *the Mafia bombed the famous Uffizi art gallery in Florence*, or is it dummy-it for to-infinitve phrase - *to strike at the kind of historic monuments that are the pride of Italy*?

Comment: Though it might be possible that we can interpret this "it" either way, I believe that any analysis that rules out the possibility of "it" referring to Mafia is wrong. [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/Mafia) (BrE) clearly states that *Mafia* "can be followed by a singular or plural verb". Google Ngram and a quick googling also clearly show the favor toward the use of *the Mafia is*, both in eng_us and eng_gb corpuses.

Comment: I think that in context, JMB's answer is clearly the correct one.

Comment: The way I mentally parsed OP was that the original author dropped semantic info as follows: "It was clearly in the mood **(of the Mafia)** to strike at the kind of historic monuments that are the pride of Italy." I think if one parses the sentence that way, then I'm not sure "Mafia" can be the antecedent of "It". (@snailplane)

Comment: What would "it" refer to in the following:  **It is clearly in the mood (of this site) to write thank-you acknowledgements at the bottom of question-posts (rather than at the top).**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think "it" refers to the Mafia; describing its desire to do damage to Italy's pride by attacking historic monuments.

Answer (score 0):

In my view the use of "it" is in a way that the reader stumbles and really asks what does "it" refer to and when the reader stumbles in his/her reading then another formulation would be preferable.
I would tend to say that "it" is the precursory subject to the main subject "to strike".
When you refer "it" to the previous sentence than "it" would stand for "this criminal act", but that is not explicitly said in the previous sentence.
And if "it" would refer to "Mafia" the normal pronoun would be "they" as "Mafia" is a group of persons.

Comment: Just to note regarding last sentence, collective nouns can be used in both singular and plural.  See [Plural Noun Forms at http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/plurals.htm#collective_noun) @DamkerngT

Comment: Note that in the first paragraph of the quoted passage, the Mafia is referred to with *it*: "And it plotted to blow up the  magnificent, ancient tower in Pisa." *They* is used to refer to the members of the Mafi, the Mafiosi.

Answer (score 0):

**The "Anticipatory It"**

This is called an "anticipatory it".  (Submitted after additional research.)  The word "it" stands for the subject which is moved after the predicate.  **That means your original 2nd choice was correct (although I question your choice of calling it a "dummy it"; see below).**

> **ORIGINAL SENTENCE:** It **was clearly in the mood** *to strike at the kind of historic monuments that are the pride of Italy*.

Rearranged:

> **REARRANGED TO REMOVE ANTICIPATORY "IT":** *To strike at the kind of historic monuments that are the pride of Italy* **was clearly in the mood**.

The then subject is the phrase *To strike at the kind of historic monuments that are the pride of Italy*.

**Dummy It?**
The question is whether one would consider this a "dummy it".  I have not found a definitive expert's opinion, but I think not since it's functionally acting as a substitute for an actual subject.  Compare with "It is raining." In this latter case, the "dummy it" is a placeholder that preserves the need for a subject only because English grammar mandates such. But other than that, the "dummy it" refers to nothing, has no meaning whatsoever, and cannot be replaced with anything.

**References:**
 - http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~kay/bcg/extrap.html
 - http://www.englishforums.com/English/LexicalBundlesStartingAnticipatory-It/bbghph/post.htm
 - ["It must have been a powerful wizard to ... " -- is "it" a pronoun or a dummy?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5890/is-this-it-a-pronoun-or-dummy-it)
 - http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/minor/dummy.htm
 - http://www.englishforums.com/English/WhatPartSpeechSentences/bbwpvl/post.htm

Comment: Your sentence, "to strike at the kind of historic monuments that are the pride of Italy was clearly in the mood", doesn't make any sense to me.  How can the notion of striking at something be in any kind of mood?

Comment: It's not my sentence. I just did a proper grammatical transformation. I think the problem is that somewhere in the semantics, style, or word-choice by the original author was not the best.

Comment: And I might add, I think the original sentence has the exact same problem of sense/semantics.  It's only an illusion due to the "anticipatory it" that the original sentence seems to make more sense.  In a similar example (not exactly the same), "It is raining." has no more sense then "Is raining." One may ask of the latter, "Huh?  What is raining?"  One doesn't ask that of the former only because of the "dummy it".

Comment: The construction you are talking about is what grammarians call a *cleft sentence*. This construction requires the predicate of the underlying proposition to be expressed as a relative clause: an underlying "SUBJ-VERB-COMPL" is rewritten as "It BE SUBJ who/that VERB-COMPL". OP's sentence has no relative clause and does not qualify.

Comment: @StoneyB I'm not sure what you mean. The original sentence is not a cleft sentence and I never suggested that it was.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis Sorry, extraposited *it* never occurred to me (and I like your term better - that extraposited *it* was never inposited to begin with). But I still think this is an ordinary personal pronoun = the Mafia.

Comment: @StoneyB That is fascinating: it also never occurred to me to think of a  '`simple ordinary personal pronoun`' because I never parsed the sentence that way.

Comment: I think "in the mood" argues against your reading: *people* are in the mood to do something, but a general sentiment is "in the air".

Comment: @StoneyB I agree 100% on that. I came to the same conclusion several days ago and have been trying to "figure that out". Back to the other point, neither of us understood the other's viewpoint, and that has led me to another answer, which is kind of philosophical and relativistic. I'm very hesitant to "go so far" on ell.se, but I think I can make it work cooperatively/synergistically with the other answer and comments.

Comment: Oh, try it on. If you don't like it you can always kill it. Or you can invent a new question it fits better.